# Microsoft SQL - Counting total of matching values in other table

Tags: sql, return-value, matching, counting

I have a SQL data scructure like this.

```
Table 1
http://pbrd.co/1x6TAl3

Table 2
http://pbrd.co/1x6TIRw
```

I'm trying to count the number of times each item_num has been sold based on the `item_qty` value in the second table.
Each item_num can appear multiple times in the second table.
I need a way to add the `total item_qty` for each associated `item_num` and output it to show how many times an item has been sold.

The correct output ordering by total quantity sold in descending order should look like this.

```
item_num: 4 7 6 
qty_sold: 11 5 4
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please edit your question to include all relevant data, no links to external sources: I have no idea what that link is, and I'm definitely not going to go to it.

Comment: What do you mean by *Microsoft SQL* ?? Microsoft **SQL Server** the server-based database product, or Microsoft **Access** with SQL ?? Please add the relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   a.item_num
   , SUM(b.item_qty) as "qty_sold"
FROM
   Table1 a
LEFT JOIN
   Table2 b
ON a.item_num = b.item_num
GROUP BY
   a.item_num
ORDER BY
   qty_sold DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.Item_num , A.Item_name , sum(B.Item_Qty) from Table1  as A inner join Table2 as B
on A.Item_num=B.Item_num
group by A.Item_num , A.Item_name
```

result:

```
item_num    item_name     Item_qty
   1            A             1
   2            B             1
   4            D             11
   6            F             4
   7            G             5
```